# What is the new official way to get from a controller the value of an instance variable of an other one controller

Tags: ember.js

What is the new way to get from a controller the value of an instance variable of an other controller.

For instance, I was using before I was using before 
`App.router.get("applicationController.isLoopingEnabled")` to access the value and `App.router.set("applicationController.isLoopingEnabled")` to set the value of `isLoopingEnabled` variable from my `PlaybarController` instance.

I just want to know what is the best practice right now on Ember RC3. I'm experiencing a lot of problems to upgrade from the pre-version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't "one way" to access properties of different controllers anymore.  It depends on where you want to access it from.

**To access a controller from another controller:**

Use the [Controller's `needs` depedency](http://emberjs.com/guides/controllers/dependencies-between-controllers/)

Example:

```
App.PostsController = Em.ArrayController.extend({
  someValue: 1
});

App.CommentsController = Em.ArrayController.extend({
  needs: ['posts'],
  postsValuePlusOne: function() {
    return this.get('controllers.posts.someValue') + 1;
  }).property('controllers.posts.someValue')
});
```

**To access a controller from a route:**

```
App.PostsController = Em.ArrayController.extend({
  someValue: 1
});

App.CommentsRoute = Em.Route.extend({
  renderTemplate: function() {
    var someValue = this.controllerFor('posts').get('someValue');
  }
});
```

**To access a controller from a view:**

```
App.PostsController = Em.ArrayController.extend({
  someValue: 1
});

App.PostsView = Em.View.extend({
  someValueBinding: 'controller.someValue'
});
```

If you want to access a value of a controller other than the view's controller (for example CommentsController, use the controller's needs: `controller.controllers.comments.someValue`

Finally,

There is a global method to access any controller, **but use this only for debugging and testing, never in production**:

```
var postsController = App.__container__.lookup('controller:posts')
```